# Hacer un SELECT para comprobación de datos [PHP+Mysql]

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando un programa en PHP+Mysql en el que realizo una inserción de datos en el que inserto un regalo a un niño pero no debe permitir añadir dos veces el mismo regalo al mismo niño.
Se que debería de hacer antes un select donde busque si hay alguna fila que tenga como id_nino el que quiero meter y como id_regalo el que quiero meter, y si hay una que coincida, pues ese método tiene que devolver un mensaje de que no puede incluirlo porque existe.
Sin embargo, no consigo dar con este paso para poder realizarlo.
Un saludo y gracias.

```html
<?php
require_once('Utils.php');

class Busqueda
{
    protected $_conexion;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_conexion = Utils::conectar();
    }

    public function insertPedir($id_juguete, $id_nino){
    
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pedir (id_juguete, id_nino) VALUES ('" . $id_juguete . "', '" . $id_nino . "')";
        return $this->_conexion->query($sql);
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: Tienes 2 opciones, 1 validas con un query "SELECT * FROM pedir WHERE id_juguete='juguete' AND id_nino='nino'" o en su defecto colocar una llave conjunta del id y niño para que sql no te deje guardar

Comment: Muchas gracias @JosueVargas! Tenía ya planteado ese SELECT pero lo que no consigo la lógica de la comprobación, de que si existe ya ese juguete para ese niño te salga error y si no que te haga el insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías crear una función aparte y comprobar si este existe mediante un `"SELECT count(*) existe FROM pedir WHERE id_juguete = ? AND id_nino = ?"`

Este te va devolver en el caso de que exista un registro `1` y `0` cuando no existe nada.
Después puedes hacer un comprobación de esta manera:
`$bool = ($existe === 1) ? true : false;`

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
class Busqueda
{
    
    public function __construct(
        protected $_conexion = null,
    )
    {
        $this->_conexion = Utils::conectar();
    }

    protected function checkPedir($id_juguete, $id_nino) : bool
    {
        // Sentencia
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) existe FROM pedir WHERE id_juguete = ? AND id_nino = ?";
        // Sentencia preparada
        $stmt = $this->_conexion->prepare($sql);
        // Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parámetros
        $stmt->bind_param('ii',$id_juguete,$id_nino);
        // Ejecutar sentencia
        $stmt->execute();
        // Vincula variables a una sentencia preparada para el almacenamiento de resultados
        $stmt->bind_result($existe);
        // Obtiene los resultados de una sentencia preparadas en las variables vinculadas
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        // Comprobamos si existe algun registro en la BD y devolvemos un Boolean.
        $bool = ($existe === 1) ? true : false;
        
        return $bool;
    }

    public function insertPedir($id_juguete, $id_nino){
        // Comprobamos en la BD si ya hemos regalado el jueguete al niño
        $bool = $this->checkPedir($id_juguete, $id_nino);
        
        // true (existe)
        if ($bool) {
            return 'Ya se regalo este juguete al niño.';
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO pedir (id_juguete, id_nino) VALUES ('" . $id_juguete . "', '" . $id_nino . "')";
            return $this->_conexion->query($sql);
        }    
    } 
}

?>
```